# Creating a shell script to check network connectivity

Tags: bash, shell

I'm making a simple shell script that runs an infinite loop, then if the output of the ping command contains "time" (indicating that it pinged successfully) it should echo "Connected!", sleep 1, and clear. However, I get no output from my script.

```
#!/bin/bash
while :
do
    if [[ $(ping google.com) == *time* ]]; 
    then
        echo -en '\E[47;32m'"\033[1mS\033[0m"
        echo "Connected!"
    else
        echo -en '\E[47;31m'"\033[1mZ\033[0m"
        echo "Not Connected!"
    fi
    clear
    sleep 1
done
```

Comment: When are you expecting `ping` to quit to let the rest of your script continue?

Comment: This is also a horribly abusive test. If you want to test that you can reach off your machine try your gateway or a DNS request, etc. Something using a server you actually have a relationship with and a bit less intensive then a ping to a random remote server.

Comment: Also `ping` returns exit codes that tell you whether it worked or not. No need to string match.

Comment: Ugh! Don't embed terminal-specific codes in your scripts - use `tput` instead to appropriately give control codes appropriate to the `$TERM` at the time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your script is not giving output because `ping` never terminates. To get `ping` to test your connectivity, you'll want to give it a run count (`-c`) and a response timeout (`-W`), and then check its return code:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
    if ping -c 1 -W 5 google.com 1>/dev/null 2>&1 
    then
        echo "Connected!"
        break
    else
        echo "Not Connected!"
        sleep 1
    fi
done
```

`ping` will return `0` if it is able to ping the given hostname successfully, and nonzero otherwise.

It's also worth noting that an iteration of this loop will run for a different period of time depending on whether `ping` succeeds quickly or fails, for example due to no network connection. You may want to keep the iterations to a constant length of time -- like 15 seconds -- using `time` and `sleep`.